# pd.timestamp 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, timestamp

For some reasons, this method below is raising the exception

> 'module' object is not callable"

on the following function:

```
import pandas as pd
import time 
def give_time_string():
    time_code = str(pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('_%d_%m_%Y'))
    return time_code
```

I've imported pandas in an earlier cell.

Comment: It returns it or does it raise it as an Exception?

Comment: How do your imports look like? (Minor point, unrelated to your question: You don't need the `str(...)`, `.strftime` already returns a `str`.)

Comment: That looks fine. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69491932/edit) the _full_ traceback into your question? Do you work with a Jupyter notebook? If so, you should also add the `jupyter-notebook` tag to your question.

Comment: I've just tried the code in a notebook: works fine? Could you add the full error message (traceback) to the question?

Comment: I tried it again it works now - that's wierd